# Execute stored procedure with parameter from other table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a procedure with one parameter, letsay `@AssetID int`.

I want to select a column value from another table, then use that value as the parameter for this procedure.

I've stored procedure something like this and the table has been filtered with "Where" criteria from `@AssetID` parameter:

```
declare @inspectyear as nvarchar(max), @calc as nvarchar(max), @query as nvarchar(max);

set @inspectyear = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(InspectYear) from ##t2 c
                  for XML path(''), type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @calc = ', ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + '  - ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)-2) 
         + ' as Calc1, ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + ' - ' + quotename(min(InspectYear)) 
         + ' as Calc2' from #t2;

set @query =
';with data as
(
      select      inspectyear,
                  partno, Pos, number
      from #t2
      unpivot
      (
            number
            for Pos in ([Pos1], [Pos2], [Pos3], [Pos4])
      ) unpvt
)
select * ' + @calc + ' into ##temp
from data
pivot
(
      sum(number)
      for inspectyear in (' + @inspectyear + ')
) pvt
order by partno';

exec sp_executesql @query = @query;
select * from ##temp;
drop table ##temp;
```

So I need to create another procedure, for instance:

```
create procedure spExecmyProc
as
begin
    exec spMyProc '@AssetID' -- <-- The parameter took from other table.
go
end
```

The `@date` parameter, took from other table.

Is it possible to do that? The result should be only one result.

So far, this is what I did. It works, but the result is not on "one result". It create more than one result if the `@AssetID` is more than one:

```
declare @AssetID int;
declare cur CURSOR FOR
select distinct AssetID from myTable

open cur
fetch next from cur into @AssetID
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
   exec mySPName @AssetID
   fetch next from cur into @AssetID
end
close cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you declare a variable, store value from that table in the variable and pass variable as parameter to your SP?

Comment: @shree.pat18, don't know how to do that. But I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to be able to be able to run some code on each value of `AssetID` in `mytable`, returning just one result for each input value, I think you could use a Scalar-valued Function. Let's pretend that the purpose of your original stored procedure was just to increment the `AssetId` value by 1 for simplicity - your function could be created like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnMyFunction (@AssetId INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return INT
    SET @return = @AssetId + 1
    RETURN  @return
END
```

If you then have some values in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Assets (
    AssetId INT
)

INSERT INTO Assets
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 7
UNION
SELECT 5
```

You can call your function on each value you return:

```
SELECT  AssetId, 
        dbo.fnMyFunction(AssetId) AS AssetIdPlus1 
FROM Assets
```

Which gives these results for my super simple dataset defined above:

```
/------------------------\
| AssetId | AssetIdPlus1 |
|---------+--------------|
|    1    |       2      |
|    2    |       3      |
|    3    |       4      |
|    5    |       6      |
|    7    |       8      |
|    5    |       6      |
\------------------------/
```

If you just want to get the result for each unique value of `AssetId` in your table, then just return the `DISTINCT` results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AssetId, 
    dbo.fnMyFunction(AssetId)
FROM Assets
```

which would give these results for the same dataset above (with just one row for `AssetId = 5`):

```
/------------------------\
| AssetId | AssetIdPlus1 |
|---------+--------------|
|    1    |       2      |
|    2    |       3      |
|    3    |       4      |
|    5    |       6      |
|    7    |       8      |
\------------------------/
```

Comment: the problem is, my Sp here is too long to be provided. It's a dynamic result from pivot query. So I need to get the "AssetID" one by one then make it into single result.

Comment: Regardless of how long or complicated your current stored procedure is, you should be able to explain to us the nature of its input(s) and output(s), or explain the overall problem you're trying to solve so we can help suggest whether this is even the best way to achieve it.

Comment: @Haminteu - I'm happy to discuss this with you [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50591/execute-stored-procedure-with-parameter-from-other-table) if you'd like.